# an error occurred while merging the default value and auto increment

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1067

SQL query:

```
ALTER TABLE `x` CHANGE `y` `y` INT( 9 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1000' AUTO_INCREMENT
```

MySQL said:

> Documentation 1067 - Invalid default value for 'y' 
>   whether the default value can be combined with auto increment in mysql

What is the correct MySQL syntax?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
ALTER TABLE `x` CHANGE `y` `y` INT( 9 ) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT
```

You just can't define default value for auto_increment.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you want to do is set the starting value of the AUTO_INCREMENT. That you do by:

`ALTER TABLE x AUTO_INCREMENT=1000`